# How to properly setup json string for curl php

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

I got these two example.

Example1:

```
$data1 = "{'username':'myUserName','password':'myPassWord'}";
```

and Example2:

```
$username= "myUserName";
$password= "myPassWord";
$data2 = "{'username':'".$username."','password':'".$password."'}";
```

Which i send to cUrl post request in php.
First example works while second does not. Why is that?
I also tried setting variables in associative array, then using json_encode, then send it to cUrl. Nothing works except first example. I'm losing my mind here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For valid [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), you need to use double quotes, so change

```
$data2 = "{'username':'".$username."','password':'".$password."'}";
```

to

```
$data2 = '{"username":"' . $username . '", "password":"' . $password . '"}';
```

---

EDIT: a sharp remark by @LawrenceCherone, to ensure you don't run into trouble with usernames/passwords that carry `"` in them, always use `json_encode()` e.g.:

```
<?php
$username= "myUserName";
$password= 'my"PassWord'; // password containing "
$arr = ['username' => $username, 'password' => $password];
$result = json_encode($arr);
```

Output `$result`: Valid JSON

```
{"username":"myUserName","password":"my\"PassWord"}
```

Comment: some usernames/passwords contain `"` which will break the JSON

Comment: Correct, and I sincerly invite @VeljkoStefanovic to accept your answer. Love the `json_encode(compact(...))`

Answer (score 1):

Dont build your own json! Use `json_encode()` instead, and use `compact()` to make an array from global vars.

```
<?php
$username= "myUserName";
$password= "myPassWord";

$data2 = json_encode(compact('username', 'password'));
```

use `$data2` for whatnot, which will contain:

```
{"username":"myUserName","password":"myPassWord"}
```